# MLCC capacitor - AC voltage performance

Tags: voltage, capacitor, ac, mlcc

I'm planning to replace an MLCC capacitor (250 VAC voltage rate) with a capacitor MLCC (650 VDC voltage rate).
Regarding the two datasheet of component I'm facing to this curve below :
[image]

[image]

Can any one help me to understand the meaning of such curve. My capacitor is 100 nF (650 VDC).

I thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Can any one help me to understand the meaning of such curve.*

It's indicating a safe operating area for current. As frequency rises and VAC is held constant, the current rises so, using the solid black line at 100 kHz (for the 100 nF capacitor), there is an AC RMS voltage limit of about 220 volts and, I expect that at 1000 kHz, the applied voltage limit is one-tenth of this at 20 volts AC (RMS).

In other words, this graph is ensuring that you don't put too much current through the capacitor.

Comment: @Andy aka: Thanks for your answer. But for current I have another curve in the datasheet named typical AC current Performance.

Comment: @geek225 well only you have the data sheet so if you don't want to share then what can folk do?

Comment: So If I understand your response, it means that If I apply 220 VAC (at 300 KHz) I may damage the capacitor ?

Comment: I believe so but I don't have a data sheet to look at.

Comment: 220 volts RMS at 100 kHz into a 100 nF capacitor produces an RMS current of 13.82 amps so, it sounds like it's going to be around the limit but I can't tell because I haven't a data sheet.

Comment: I have added AC current performance curve to my initial question.

Comment: It tallies with my calculation of 13.8 amps at 100 kHz for the 100 nF capacitor.

Comment: How can we explain an exceed of current may destroy a capacitor. Is there any relationship which explain this ?

Comment: Fusing current of wires and internal cap plates I expect but this is a side issue to your original question and this isn't a discussion forum where evolving questions are naturally tolerated or welcomed.